# Time complexity of printing the longest path in a binary search tree

Tags: javascript, search, tree, time-complexity, binary-search-tree

**Problem**: given a binary search tree, print out the longest path.

**Approach**: Store the possible depths at each level and filter out the longest one. The time complexity of this must be at *least* `O(n)` because we are calculating the diameter of the tree in some sense. However, at each level, we are calling `reduce` on an array of possible paths in order to determine the longest path at each stage. I think this would make the complexity `O(nk)` where `k` is the length of the array at each stage. Space complexity would be O(n + k + j) where n is the depth of the recursive call and k and j are the arrays.

**Question**: is this analysis of the time complexity correct, and two, how can this be done in just `O(n)` time?

```
function printLongestPath(root = this.head, paths = [], finishedPaths = []) {

        if (!root) return;

        paths.push(root.data);

        if (!root.left && !root.right) {
            finishedPaths.push(paths);
            paths.pop();
            return;
        }

        this.printLongestPath(root.left, paths, finishedPaths);
        this.printLongestPath(root.right, paths, finishedPaths);

        // Pop once more once both paths have finished because it means we are in an intermediary step

        paths.pop();


        return finishedPaths.reduce((longest, current) => {
          return current.length > longest.length ? current : longest
        }, finishedPaths[0]);

    }
```

Comment: The code looks very weird, does it work? You are not using finishedPaths anywhere.

Comment: @PalashBansal You're right, it was a typo, see the edit. It was supposed to be used at the end.